# Medical Bill Consolidation

Tags: united-states, healthcare, billing

I've recently had two procedures done and now the medical bills are rolling in. The billing days and services are spaced out and varied, making management frustrating, but not impossible. That being said, I will soon be out of my grace period for student loans, adding another layer of frustration.

In short, is there a strategy for somehow consolidating my medical bills into a single monthly payment to avoid having to manage the multitude of bills and payment plans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are definitely ways to retroactively consolidate medical bills -- there's an entire industry of companies offering debt consolidation (many of which are scummy/predatory, be careful! See https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0150-coping-debt and some decent articles at http://blog.readyforzero.com/are-there-legitimate-debt-consolidation-loans and http://blog.readyforzero.com/how-to-find-a-reputable-debt-consolidation-company).

In general, what you are looking to do is take out a loan, possibly at a better interest rate than whatever you are being charged currently, and pay off the medical bills. If you are not paying interest on the medical bills and are just being allowed to spread out the payments, you are already golden and should just put up with the ups and downs.

If you have any equity in a home, take out a home equity loan or line of credit, pay off your medical bills. Rates are still great right now. Even if you have no home equity to tap, if you have a steady job you might be able to get a nice small loan from a local bank or peer-to-peer lending site. Do your homework and only work with reputable companies, especially if doing things online.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't have to pay interest, so I suppose it may just be best to put up with it as you suggested. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, or not retroactively. There really are multiple companies involved, each of which bills you separately for the services they provided.

This can be *partly* avoided by selecting either a high-end health plan with lower out-of-pocket maximum, (costs more up front, of course) or by selecting a genuine Health Management Organization (not a PPO) which gathers more of the services into a single business. Either of these would result in fewer cash payments needing to be sent.

But I don't know of any way to simplify things after the fact. Even if there was a consolidation service, you would have to forward the bills to them, which really wouldn't be any easier than just paying the bills.

(I'm assuming you are in the US, where we have a health insurance system rather than a health system. Other countries may handle this differently.)

Comment: Hmmm. After my google searches turned up no results, I figured this would probably be the case. I'll just stick to keeping track of everything. In any event, thanks for the answer!